# Stop windows 10 from popping things up

Tags: windows-10

Ever since the very last windows update, I've had 2 very annoying pop-ups coming at me non-stop.

<strike>1. It's *constantly* asking me to sign in to my 'Microsoft-account'. It states there is a "problem", but there isn't. I am not using a Microsoft account. I'm running solely on local accounts....</strike> **fixed by going through windows' settings and deleting my account as a reference**

2. Every time I upload a file somewhere, for some weird reason, it opens microsoft onedrive and asks me to upload stuff to there instead....??? This might just be the most annoying thing of all. I quite often debug file uploaders on websites and such. Imagine having to go through the hassle of uploading a test file 300 times, but then also having to close onedrive 300 times... ,_,

I'm seriously considering switching to Linux if there aren't any easy fixes for this.

Running build 15063.138 btw!

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is asking you to log into your MS Account?  There are many UWP programs that require you to log into your account, and if you actually are using a local account, each program would ask you to do so (instead of it happening organically)

Comment: Ramhound windows is, through the notification thing with pop-ups. I don't use any apps or the windows store. It literally says "There is a problem with your account, click here to sign in." Clicking on it leads me to linking my windows to my MS account, which I don't want. - @Spittin'IT it says version 1703, build 15063.138

Comment: @Spittin'IT oh btw, it's about time for a clean install again, but I have malwarebytes pro running and scan daily, full scan. But this stuff very clearly started happening after the last big update, with which they've also removed extremely useful tools like the good old way to remove programs. Now I can only use the "app remover" but that useless tool doesn't even show me half the stuff that's installed on my pc...

Comment: @Spittin'IT I would agree, but I've just fixed the microsoft account thing and the microsoft cloud thing is apparently bugging a lot more people than just me. It's quite definitely linked to the last big update.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a screenshot?

Comment: @DanielB A screenshot of microsoft onedrive opening whenever the filepicker opens?

Comment: Yes, what you describe in point 2.